# Change the background colour of the page on scroll on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, animation, background

I want to change the colour of the background on a scroll, check out the effect [here](https://share.getcloudapp.com/mXumrJ4g).  I would want the same thing to happen on my website. As soon as I scroll to a particular section, using that section ID I can change the colour of the background. I want to it have the colour animation that the video file has and not so sudden. I am working on WordPress and would like the solution that will work on WordPress. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer below example, I have used the background color, you can set image instead

```js
/**
 * This was built using the scrollie jQuery Plugin
 * https://github.com/Funsella/jquery-scrollie
 */


$( window ).ready(function() {
  
    var wHeight = $(window).height();

    $('.slide')
      .height(wHeight)
      .scrollie({
        scrollOffset : -50,
        scrollingInView : function(elem) {
                   
          var bgColor = elem.data('background');
          
          $('body').css('background-color', bgColor);
          
        }
      });

  });
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box }

body {
  font-family: 'Coming Soon', cursive;
  transition: background 1s ease;
   background: #3498db;
}

p {
  color: #ecf0f1;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  
}

span {
  clear: both;
  font-size: .7em;
  color: #bdc3c7;
}

a {
  color: #c0392b;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.slide {
  
  .inside {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 3em;
    
    p {
      display: table-cell;
      width: 100%;
      clear: both;
      vertical-align: middle; 
      text-align: center; 
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2542/jquery.scrollie.min_1.js"></script>

<div class="main-wrapper">
  
  <div class="slide slide-one" data-background="#3498db">
    <div class="inside">
    <p>I Wanted to create a really simple pen</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide slide-two" data-background="#27ae60">
    <div class="inside">
      <p>A pen that uses some awesome colors <br /><span>awesome <a href="http://flatuicolors.com/" target="_blank">like these</a></span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide slide-three" data-background="#e74c3c">
    <div class="inside">
      <p>And that made you scroll</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide slide-four" data-background="#e67e22">
    <div class="inside">
      <p>Mission Accomplished</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide slide-five" data-background="#9b59b6">
    <div class="inside">
      <p>Have an awesome day</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="slide slide-five" data-background="#34495e">
    <div class="inside">
      <p>This was built a long time ago so I made a better version <a href="https://codepen.io/Funsella/pen/3271d716c5c6b67c18af6f4ecf9295af/">better version</a> </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```